# How to update in parse database custom table using android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I know about how to insert in custom table in parse.com database but i don't know about it how to update. i confuse in the how to get all object value from the table. so you have any idea about it.

Thanks in Advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to retrieve the object you want to update and then save it edited like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
query.whereEqualTo("firstName", "Dan");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            ParseObject person = list.get(0);
            person.put("firstName", "Johan");
            person.saveInBackground();
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 });
```

For more examples you could read the chapter for updating objects in Parse.com documentation here https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-updating-objects

Comment: Sorry but its not work in my side. i read whole documentation but i not get any idea about it. and also how to get objectId.

Comment: it's not necessary to get the objectId, take a look at my example above - you could get the ParseObject by some property, for example "firstName" and then edit it and save it again

Comment: i given name there Country its parse database field. and i have multiple record.

Comment: What's given in getQuery("user"). it's user is your class name??

Comment: the parameter in getQuery() is the name of the table from which you want to get an object. It is just an example with a table (or class) "User" which has a column called "firstName"

Comment: now i get the error in the list.get(0). index out of bound

Comment: this means that you don't have any results in your list, debug it and see if you have results and if you have such elements in the tables i parse.com UI

Comment: i have same key filed in database but it's cant working

Comment: i get the list size zero that why i get the error index out of bound

Comment: take a look at this picture http://www.applicationcraft.com/img/docs/parse-dash-data-d5a0f1f3.png Does your table look similar to this one? On the left is the class name (by me in the example - User) and you should set this class name as a parameter to the `getQuery(...)` method and then on the right side are the columns. In the `whereEqualTo` you should pass some of the column names.

Comment: Already i do like this but it's cant work. let's i will check this where i do the mistake.

Comment: Now it's how to delete record ? update is successfully completed.

Comment: to delete an object you should get it by the same way like the update and then in the `done` method, you should do the following thing: `ParseObject person = list.get(0);  person.deleteInBackground();`  https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-deleting-objects